# Did Pain control the animals from his Summoning jutsu?

Tags: naruto

I'm a fan of *Naruto*, I wonder if Pain was manipulating his summoned beasts, as I noticed rods in all the animals.
Also, were those animals dead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes!
According to wiki page [here](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Animal_Path) 
This is a list Pain can summon :

> The Animal Path (畜生道, Chikushōdō) grants a Rinnegan user the ability of summoning various animals and creatures to aid it in battle. These creatures appear to be immortal, as they were killed and later summoned again
>
> - Giant Drill-Beaked Bird
> - Giant Multi-Headed Dog
> - Giant Snake-Tailed Chameleon
> - Giant Panda
> - Giant Ox
> - Giant Rhino
> - Giant Crustacean
> - Giant Centipede